# How can I parse?

Tags: python

**MUC20**    17615  NP_689886.2 **MET** 01280   NP_001120972.1  in vitro;in vivo;yeast 2-hybrid 15314156

**SMURF2**  06901   NP_073576.1 **TFPI2**   08962   NP_006519.1 yeast 2-hybrid  15231748

**ERBB2**   01281   NP_004439.2 **ERBB2**   01281   NP_004439.2 in vitro;in vivo    10372802,1706616,12354693,11500516

**ACPP**    01378   NP_001127666.1  **ERBB2**   01281   NP_004439.2 in vitro;in vivo    11067847,10851066,9705354

**PIK3R1**  01381   NP_852664.1 **ERBB2**   01281   NP_004439.2 in vivo 1351056,16843263

PLCG1   01398   NP_002651.2 ERBB2   01281   NP_004439.2 in vivo 1676673,1683701

......

Plese help me. My data looks like this. I want to parse only the paired names of proteins(bold) using python. 
And the paired names should be stored like below. For example, MUC20 10 MET. And SMURF2 10 TFPI2.
Between the names, the number 10 should be inserted.

MUC20 10 MET

SMURF2 10 TFPI2

ERBB2 10 ERBB2

ACPP 10 ERBB2

How can I parse like above?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I am afraid I am a newcomer to python.

Comment: what country are you from?  what field are you working in?

Answer (score 2):

Could you split by spaces and then take the 0th & 3rd elements and insert '10' between them?

Eg:

```
def parseString(origString):
    splitString = origString.split(' ')
    return splitString[0] + ' 10 ' + splitString[3]
```

Comment: I'd go for `return '{0} 10 {3}'.format(*splitString)`

Answer (score 1):

This is (at least) three problems:

1. The parsing, i.e. identifying the information of interest in the input file, separating it from the stuff you're not interested in. Look into [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this part, perhaps.
2. Storing the parsed-out infromation in a suitable structure. A plain Python list should suffice.
3. Using the stored information to generate some other, new "report", which is where you'd insert the `10`s. This is trivial by just iterating over the list from (2).

Comment: This is a good scenario to leverage Python's generators. The parser looks like something that produces a sequence of items (where the "item" is the information extracted from e.g. one line of input text and stored somehow, like in a `dict` or `namedtuple`). The report generator looks like something that consumes this sequence by formatting it into a textual report.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need Regular expressions to resolve this problem but, if you want to use them, try:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('^(\w+)\D\d+\D\w+\D\d\D(\w+)')
groups = pattern.search(your_string).groups()
print groups[0] + ' 10 ' + groups[1]
```